# Subquery returned more than 1 value in Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

when i execute this query i got this error please help me

```
       USE [DSOG2016]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[wsp_GRN_Delete]    Script Date: 2018-09-19 09:12:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[wsp_GRN_Delete]

@grnid varchar(max),
@br_code varchar(max)
as
begin
declare @Doc_No nvarchar(50),@GrnQty numeric(18,3),@OrderNo nvarchar(50)
SET @Doc_No = (select Doc_No from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
SET @GrnQty = (select GRNQty from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
SET @OrderNo = (select OrderNo from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
delete from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code
delete from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code
delete from Inv_Trans where Doc_No=@Doc_No and Br_Code=@br_code  and Trans_Type='GRN'
update SupplierOrder set GRNNo=
                                    CASE WHEN GRNNo like '%'+@Doc_No+'%' THEN  REPLACE(GRNNo, ','+cast(@Doc_No as varchar),'')
                                    else 
                                    null
                                    END      
                     where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@br_code 
update SupplierOrder_T set GRNID=
                    CASE WHEN GRNID like '%'+cast(@grnid as varchar)+'%' THEN 
                                     REPLACE(GRNID, ','+cast(@grnid as varchar),'')
                                     else
                                     null
                                    END,

                           GRNQty=  CASE WHEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty) >0 THEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty)

                                         ELSE 0

                                   END

                     where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@br_code




end
```

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: no trigger is not used

Comment: Can you post a data sample? Though it has no bearing on your SQL here, it's always good practice to specify the size of your variably sized fields.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Are you sure there are no triggers on that table? The error message you are getting is not possible with the code posted? However, that message is **very common** with poorly written update triggers.

Comment: actually it is a part of a stored procedure...it include 5 querys....among them 3 query's is working properly..

Comment: Take another look at line number in the error message and post real query that produces this error. It is obvious that this query has no subqueries.

Comment: ok i wil post the stored procedure

Comment: it's a very long stored procedure i can't post it

Comment: i wil post the query's based on the sp

Comment: delete from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code

delete from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code



delete from Inv_Trans where Doc_No=@Doc_No and Br_Code=@Br_Code and Trans_Type='GRN'

Comment: update SupplierOrder set GRNNo=

         CASE WHEN GRNNo like '%'+@Doc_No+'%' THEN  REPLACE(GRNNo, ','+cast(@Doc_No as varchar),'')
         else 
         null
         END      

      where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@Br_Code 
     
update SupplierOrder_T set GRNID=

         CASE WHEN GRNID like '%'+cast(@grnid as varchar)+'%' THEN 
          REPLACE(GRNID, ','+cast(@grnid as varchar),'')
          else
          null
         END,

         GRNQty=  CASE WHEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty) >0 THEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty)

     ELSE 0 END
where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@Br_Code

Comment: Don't add code to the comments. This is part of your question. Instead you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52389591/edit) your question and put this information there.

Comment: And that error is not possibly coming from that code UNLESS you have  delete trigger on GRN_T or an update trigger on SupplierOrder. My guess is you have more code and that is where the issue is.

Comment: ok i edit the question and post the stored procedure

Comment: Even in what you posted, there are 9 statements that could have produced this error.  Figure out which one it is by executing them one at a time in management studio (it's probably one of the `SET` statements).  Once you've figure that out, tell us which statement and then include all of the Table and View definitions referenced by that statement.  Until then, you are asking us to take shots in the dark.

Comment: Each of three of variable assignments at the top of this SP could produce this error. What is the line number in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please you use SUB QUERY Return only one Value like.

Use Select Query TOP 1 Value.

```
Declare @Doc_No nvarchar(50)

SET @Doc_No = (select Top 1 Doc_No from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)


 USE [DSOG2016]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[wsp_GRN_Delete]    Script Date: 2018-09-19 09:12:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[wsp_GRN_Delete]

@grnid varchar(max),
@br_code varchar(max)
as
begin
declare @Doc_No nvarchar(50),@GrnQty numeric(18,3),@OrderNo nvarchar(50)
SET @Doc_No = (select TOP 1 Doc_No from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
SET @GrnQty = (select TOP 1 GRNQty from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
SET @OrderNo = (select TOP 1 OrderNo from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code)
delete from GRN where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code
delete from GRN_T where GRNID=@grnid and Br_Code=@br_code
delete from Inv_Trans where Doc_No=@Doc_No and Br_Code=@br_code  and Trans_Type='GRN'
update SupplierOrder set GRNNo=
                                    CASE WHEN GRNNo like '%'+@Doc_No+'%' THEN  REPLACE(GRNNo, ','+cast(@Doc_No as varchar),'')
                                    else 
                                    null
                                    END      
                     where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@br_code 
update SupplierOrder_T set GRNID=
                    CASE WHEN GRNID like '%'+cast(@grnid as varchar)+'%' THEN 
                                     REPLACE(GRNID, ','+cast(@grnid as varchar),'')
                                     else
                                     null
                                    END,

                           GRNQty=  CASE WHEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty) >0 THEN (GRNQty-@GrnQty)

                                         ELSE 0

                                   END

                     where Doc_No=@OrderNo and Br_Code=@br_code




end
```